# questions for spring security config

Tags: spring, spring-security

I`ve tried to config Spring Security.

This is my sucurity config.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // @formatter:off
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/**", "/denied**").permitAll()                
            .anyRequest().denyAll()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/denied")
            .and()
            .csrf().disable();
    // @formatter:on
}
```

When I access url "localhost:8080/admin", I expect "/denied" page.
But it shows default 403 page provided spring security.
Is there any problem my configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:
Change `.anyRequest().denyAll()` to `.anyRequest().authenticated()`

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
// @formatter:off
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api/**", "/denied**").permitAll()                
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/denied")
        .and()
        .csrf().disable();
// @formatter:on
}
```

If u need to use `requiresSecure()`, just add `.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure().and()` after `.and()`

Comment: Thanks. I just want to response 403 status text (e.g. {"error" : "blahblah"}) if user request to non defined endpoint. So I set the accessDeniedPage("/denied"). But It shows default 403 page.

Comment: When you set `.anyRequest().denyAll()`, the accessDeniedPage("/denied") also got denied. So if you just want to response 403, just change the `.antMatchers("/**").fullyAuthenticated()` to `.anyRequest().authenticated()` or you can use `AuthenticationEntryPoint`